# Multiple images on a custom table view cell (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uiimageview

I'm trying to think of how to best solve this...currently my app supports a user uploading and saving an image to Parse and then retrieving it to a UIImageView on a custom table view cell. However, how would I go about implementing multiple pictures where a user swipes the top picture and the next photo is shown, all in the same table cell? Does this require a new view? If so, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this requires a custom view. I suggest this great tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift to help you get on the right track. It includes a solution to your problem. Starting at "Paging with UIScrollView"

Answer (score -1):

Follow that tutorial that Caleb recommended but you could also use a gesture recognizer on your custom cell. You can design the cell in the storyboard, make a subclass from UITableViewCell and connect the components via outlets to your custom class.